# Could the invisible incomprehensible nature of God be the reason why Satan started a war in heaven?

Tags: nature-of-god, satan

Paul wrote a letter to Timothy and revealed an attribute of God previously unknown to man. Paul describes God Almighty as dwelling in a light that cannot be approached and that no one has ever seen God, not even the cherub angel Lucifer who is said to have been on the Holy Mountain of God and also that the very act of seeing God is not possible. This truth can be found in the Book of

**1st Timothy chapter 6 verse 16**

> who alone is immortal and who lives in unapproachable light, whom no one has seen or can see. To him be honor and might forever. Amen

Do you think this could have been the deception the cherub Lucifer might have used to deceive a third of the angels in heaven that how could they worship God whose voice they can hear but whose form they cannot see? Did Lucifer demand of God to show his form or they rebel?

The number of angels in heaven is in the millions, because of this truth from the book of revelation where John sees a vision of angels around the throne worshipping Him who lives forever.

**Revelation 5:11**

> Then I looked and heard the voice of many angels, numbering thousands upon thousands, and ten thousand times ten thousand. They encircled the throne and the living creatures and the elders.

These are the angels that remained loyal to God after the rebellion, the angels that did not side with lucifer, this means that the number of angels Satan managed to deceive were also in the millions because of this truth about the deceiver of the whole world being the dragon that swept a third of the heavenly stars with its tail.

**Revelation 12:4**

> Its tail swept a third of the stars out of the sky and flung them to the earth.

I am asking if this incomprehensible nature of God where the angels literally heard His voice from within the light but could not see Him might have caused Satan to call out the angels in a meeting and asked them that they deserved a right to see(God to allow them to approach the light and see Him) the form of God else they cease worshipping Him?

There is this widely held belief that Satan tried to be like God but I think he was well aware that he was a created being like other angels besides this is not mentioned explicitly anwhere in scripture.

Comment: I cannot see that this is the place to open a discussion of this kind. This site examines _comparative_ Christianity, that is to say it questions (and answers) what is said and done by self-identifying Christian Groups. This 'question' forms a thesis for discussion  but has done no research as to whether any Groups actually _hold_ this as a doctrine.

Comment: What is the connection between the light of God and his supposedly "incomprehensible nature"?  You could look at me or an image of me (a photograph) but that would tell you nothing about my nature, only my appearance.

Comment: @Lesley, you cannot approach the light and you cannot see his form but you can hear his voice from the light just like He said "This is my beloved Son with whom I am pleased with, listen to him"

Comment: As I said in a comment to you re. another Q, I would be happy to answer a Q on 1 Tim. 6:16, but this one goes off at an unrelated tangent. There is no warrant to introduce Satan into the matter of God dwelling in unapproachable light. Your points are just not logically connected. Can you just stick to a Q based on 1 Tim. 6:16?

Comment: @Anne, I do agree and i have read a catholic encyclopedia where they allege that the devil revolted because of God's desire to merge himself with a form lower than the angel's `man` which God did anyway by merging with the body of Jesus Christ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the essay "Satan's Triad of Vices" by Robert C. Fox, the author makes a connection between Milton's Paradise Lost and ideas from Saint Gregory's "Moralia in Job". The triad of vices that motivate Satan is given as:

- pride
- envy
- revenge

Revenge cannot be the motive for the fall, since Satan in his original state would not yet have suffered harm for which he might have cause for seeking revenge. Revenge is a response, not an initial cause.

That leaves envy and pride. Here is a quote concerning the categories of pride:

> Pride, of course, is Satan's most obvious trait, but the exact nature
> of this pride is far more complex than may appear at first glance. In
> characterizing his Satan as an embodiment of this vice, Milton seems
> to have been guided by a concept first set forth by St. Gregory the
> Great in the *Moralia in Job*. Pride, according to the teachings of St.
> Gregory, is a vice that arises from any of several improper attitudes
> towards a good. Sin results when one maintains that a good he
> possesses comes from himself and not from God (**originative pride**);
> when he admits that it comes from God but maintains that he has
> received it as a due reward for his own merits (**meritorious pride**);
> when he boasts of possessing a good which in reality he does not have
> (**boastful pride**) ; or when he despises others and wishes to be the
> sole possessor of a good (**exclusive pride**).

The motive you propose could align with some of these dimensions of pride.

**The creation**. Was the universe mostly created by God's direct action with the angels being mere spectators? Or did God delegate many details to the angels? If the latter, then the parts of creation that Satan shaped he might claim as being made by his own power, hence originative pride.

**Rule**. Clearly, in wanting to displace God, he possessed exclusive pride.

**Appearance**. God cannot be seen but Satan as Lucifer was a gloriously visible being, perceptible to the other angels. As Ezekiel 28 says, he was adorned adorned with "carnelian, chrysolite and emerald, topaz, onyx and jasper, lapis lazuli, turquoise and beryl." Believing his kind of glory was greater than God's gives him boastful pride. Believing it flows from his own nature not a gift of God is another example of originative pride.

This third idea of an angel of light thinking himself greater than one who cannot be seen seems to come closest to your question. While it is plausible, Scripture mostly describes and judges Satan's actions and words, but is silent about his motives. Revelation 12 tells us that he grows angry and desperate when he realizes that his time is short. In The Book of Job, he tries to paint God as a liar and he as telling the truth and also incited Eve to envy, which flows form his own envy. In Job we see that he shows his pride by thinking that he is smarter than God in that he predicts that Job will curse God if made to suffer. In Matthew, the temptations he lobs at Jesus show that Satan covets worship, showing his envy. Thus we can attribute some motives to Satan, but the one you suggest is not an obvious one.

However, as a tactical device, it seems clear that Satan relies upon God's hiddenness, transcendence, and how far off in time and space is the Lord's wisdom to create a wedge between people and God. Eve falls because God does not immediately intervene and challenge Satan's words. Job suffers and nearly falls because the Whirlwind does not come immediately when Job calls for help. Job complains that the path to wisdom is unknown to mankind.

So the hiddenness and invisibility of God presents Satan with opportunities to create doubt and persuade via stealth and feed on our impatience and uncertainty. They are only opportunities because of faith, or rather its lack. Satan recognize that God's entire system, rule and mode of intercourse is built upon faith. The hiddenness is a fundamental underpinning of this. Thus he can rule the world of unbelief, just as the Lord rules the world of belief. To have a world to rule and subjects, he must create them out of the people God intended to be people of faith. The irony is that to leverage God's invisibility to his seeming advantage, he must work to hide the invisible God from us. How futile is it to attempt to hide that which is already invisible?

Comment: You forgot the word "anointing" in Ezekiel28, God had "anointed" Lucifer, that enable him to pass thru a "fiery stones", the region of seraphim. This is the source of Satan's pride. Lucifer having placed in the Holy Mountain had seen the "Wisdom" seated on the Throne, and he desires that God will anoint him once again of the "Spirit of Wisdom", for greater illumination and be glorified by sitting on the Throne. But ofcourse, the Spirit of Wisdom is destined to rest in the tabernacle of the chosen Woman(Sirach24:12), and needed to be hewn first, by Seven Sorrows or Seven Swords. -Proverbs9:1

Comment: Well answered, his envy was pride coming from being covered by every precious stone.

Comment: We will never understand why the angels chose Lucifer, a created being over their real creator, God.

Answer (score -1):

**Could the invisible incomprehensible nature of God be the reason why Satan started a war in heaven?**

The answer is NO!

The primary reason why Satan started a war in Heaven, or what is well known as "Non-Serviam, is because, Lucifer thinks, God deprived him of his desire to sit on the Throne.

Lucifer is the bearer of Light, and God bestowed him/her beauty that surpasses all the created angels, but ofcourse, Satan being a cherub, is still lower than a seraph.

But we know in Ezekiel28:12-ff, that God "anointed" Lucifer that enable him/her to pass the "fiery stones", the region of the Seraphim, an archangels higher than cherubim. And os, the anointing gave some pride to Lucifer, and at the same time, God placed him in the Holy Mountain.

What did Lucifer saw in the Holy Mountain?

Lucifer saw a "Spirit of Wisdom" seated on the Throne.

Spirit of Wisdom can be given in the form of anointing, like what happen to Jesus in the Baptism in the River Jordan, and Jesus became for us the Wisdom of God. And also, we can this happening in the Upper Room, where the Spirit of Wisdom resided in the Immaculate Heart of Mary that was hen by Seven Swords or Seven Sorrows. -Proverbs9:1

Lucifer desires to be anointed by God, and desires to sit on the Throne, and the way to realize it, is by receiving God's anointing. Until, God called all the angels and revealed His Divine Plan and sending the Logos, and be incarnated, and the Spirit of Wisdom, is meant for Jesus as His anointing to fulfill His redemptive mission as "Christ" or the "Anointed One". And this made Lucifer felt deprived of his dream.

But, there's more, Lucifer, got even angry when God reveals, that the Spirit of Wisdom is ultimately created for the chosem Woman, because the chosen Woman is destined to sit on the Throne, as the Sovereign Queen of Heaven and Earth, and the Spirit of Created Wisdom will perfectly, completely and mystically dwell in Mary's Immaculate Heart, but firstm it need to hewn by Seven Swords or Seven Sorrows.

Lucifer's taught that God placed him in the Holy Mountain, and later on be anointed with Wisdom, and so Lucifer, boast about this with the Third of the Angels, and promised them, that he will give them Wisdom too and enlighten them about the mysteries of God. And so, the Third of the Angels made an allegiance with Lucifer, and also, joined Lucifer in his/her rebellion after, their plan did not push thru.

This is the reason why Lucifer, after he was cast out, portrays a desires to become a queen to be worship, because he realized that God's Divine Plan, was to gave Mary the chosen Woman the Spirit of Wisdom as Her anointing forever in eternity, as the Sovereign Queen of Heaven and Earth.

This is the product of my lifetime studies of scriptures, and aided by the formation of wisdom in the School of Mary. And if this answer need citations, I will gladly put in a ton of citations to prove, that Mary is the chosen Woman, destined to sit in the Throne at the Holy Mountain, because the Spirit of Wisdom shall rest in Her tabernacle.

> "The creator my maker, rest in my tabernacle." -Sirach24:12

Ave!